# Python Read files and append to a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

I'm trying to read multiple files in a folder. I have around 100 files. I'm using the below code to read a file and append it to a data frame. There seems to be an issue with the index. After data frame is created, the columns are getting swapped. eg:

> File 1 gets appended in the format ID, NAME, ADDRESS, COORDINATES
>
> File 2 gets appended in the format NAME, COORDINATES, ADDRESS, ID

This is causing the values to be in wrong columns.

Code:

```
path=r"C:\Notebooks\temp"
filenames = glob.glob(path+"/*.csv")
dfs=[]

for file in range(len(filenames)):
    data_read=pd.read_csv(filenames[file], header=0)
    dfs.append(data_read)
    big_frame=pd.concat(dfs)
```

Is there a better way to read CSV files and append to a dataframe?

Comment: you can may be try a list comprehension here : `big_frame = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(i) for i in filenames])` , as for your code , i think `big_frame=pd.concat(dfs)` should be outside the loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to erase the last line since it is useless and make dfs not a list but an empty Dataframe

```
dfs = pd.DataFrame(data={'ID' :str(0), 'NAME':str(0), 'ADDRESS':0, 'COORDINATES':str(0)}]
```

Then append all the other files to it as you did and at the end you can eliminate the first observation since it is just an 'initializer'.

For what concerns the problem about columns name, try this:

```
column_names = ["ID", "NAME", "ADDRESS", "COORDINATES"]

for file in range(len(filenames)):
    data_read=pd.read_csv(filenames[file], header=0).reindex(columns=column_names)
    dfs.append(data_read)
```

Make the two pieces together and you obtain the final code:

```
path=r"C:\Notebooks\temp"
filenames = glob.glob(path+"/*.csv")
dfs = pd.DataFrame(data={'ID' :str(0), 'NAME':str(0), 'ADDRESS':0, 'COORDINATES':str(0)}]
column_names = ["ID", "NAME", "ADDRESS", "COORDINATES"]

    for file in range(len(filenames)):
        data_read=pd.read_csv(filenames[file], header=0).reindex(columns=column_names)
        dfs.append(data_read)

dfs = dfs.iloc[1:,:]
```